# Js remove all classes from element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button and when I click on it I want to remove all the classes. That's what I've tried so far:

```
button.style.className = ''
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  this.style.className = '';
}
```

```css
.myClass {

  color:red;
  
}

.second {

  color:green;
}
```

```html
<button class="myClass second">click me</button>
```

Now I can't use classList.remove because I doen't know the class names, they are dynamic.

How can I remove all the classes from an element?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do not access `className` from the `style` object, access it directly like

```
this.className
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  this.className = '';
}
```

```css
.myClass {

  color:red;
  
}

.second {

  color:green;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" class="myClass second">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 14):

HTML DOM `removeAttribute()` Method:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  this.removeAttribute("class");
}
```

```css
.myClass {
  background-color:red;
}

.second {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" class="myClass second">click me</button>
```

Comment: i was looking for this because edge does not support classList=' '

Comment: @EddyCharry I guess you confused `classList` with `className`.

Answer (score 11):

Use `this.classname` instead of `this.style.className`. Your Javascript code will be like this:

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
    this.className = ''; //remove the .style
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bes4csqt/).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove (.style) and after that everything works fine.

```
 button.className = '';
```

or you can use `this.className = "";`

both works fine.